# kernel 4.13 brings me initramfs when booting

Tags: boot, kernel

Due to intel hardware vulnerability I updated my ubuntu 16.04 system to kernel 4.13. Actually it was automatic. I can see the new kernel name before booting if I click shift. However it won't boot correctly. It goes to initramfs status. I did fsck.ext4 /dev/sdx, but it is not working. This is quite urgent since there is possible hacking situation due to the intel faulty cpu. How do I boot with new kernel correctly in this situation??

Comment: I am on 17.10 with kernel 4.13, because of spectre and meltdown, but booting is not possible: there is no disc decryption graphical prompt! With 4.10 there is a graphical prompt and with 4.13 rescue system there is command line interface decryption prompt and both kernels boot. Same question: How do I boot with new kernel correctly.

Comment: After the new upgrade files are available at "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade". The system boots without the initramfs stuff.  It's fine now.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will have a look... at the moment my BIOS is broken :-(

Comment: When the new kernel was not working I edited the file, "/etc/default/grub" to go back to the last working kernel. Then "sudo update-grub". Now mine works, so I changed the file setting like normal to boot from the latest kernel.

Comment: IC :-) I think the `sudo apt upgrade` is your solution, please answer your own question.

Comment: Still no booting with kernel `4.13.0-32-generic`

Comment: I filed a hardware related bug report here [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1750215)